# Windows Azure SQL Database CREATE LOGIN - Expiration policy?

Tags: sql-server, azure, authentication, passwords

I'm creating a login on a Windows Azure SQL Database as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336268.aspx).

Just a simple question: it mentions on the page that the 'CHECK_EXPIRATION' option is not supported. Am I correct to assume that this mean that no expiration policy is enforced?

I'm just concerned that our Azure app will die one day because the password for our app user has expired :(. Could somebody kindly confirm my assumption and put my mind at rest :)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) for CHECK_EXPIRATION is OFF and Windows Azure SQL Database [does not support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336268.aspx) the CHECK_EXPIRATION option, no password expiration policy will be enforced.